# How do I redirect in react native when button is clicked?

Tags: react-native

How do i go to the next screen in react native when i clicked a button?

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import Test from './android/components/Test'


export default class ReactTest extends Component {


  render() {

    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome click the button to register.
        </Text>
         <Button
                    style={styles.cancelButton} 
                    onPress={this.editUser}
                    title="Register"
                    color="#343434"
                    accessibilityLabel="Register a User."/>
      </View>


    );
  }
}
```

I am new to react-native. I am trying to navigate from one screen to another when the register button is pressed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any of the following api

- [React Native Router](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux)
- [NavigatorIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html)
- [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html)
- [Navigator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.31/docs/using-navigators.html)

But I recommend you to use [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html). Here is an example how to use [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html)

```
import {
  StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
});

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Button
        title="Go to Jane's profile"
        onPress={() =>
          navigate('Profile')
        }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @kurokocrunch can you follow this ?

Comment: Thank you @Jeffrey Rajan

Answer (score 3):

Write a function at the top before render method for editUser to direct where to navigate to.

```
editUser = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate("Screen");
      };
```